# Springboot @Controller cannot be invoked, but @RestController works

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My controller has been annotated with @Controller and it cannot be invoked
- The browser shows

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

But, if it is annotated with @RestController, then it works. My SpringBoot version:1.5.3.RELEASE

My Controller : (in com.sbootsecurityjsp.controller)

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method= RequestMethod.GET )
    public String login() {
        return "Login Controller";
    }   
}
```

Main Class: (in com.sbootsecurityjsp)

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.sbootsecurityjsp"}) 
public class SbootSecurityJspApplication {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SbootSecurityJspApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I am curious why the @Controller cannot work if the @RestController annotation works. If component scan is not working, @RestController also should not work. I have added `scanbasePackages` too. Even without `scanbasePackages`, it does not work.

By the way, when the app starts, the logs also show a line as following:

```
INFO 532 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/login],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sbootsecurityjsp.controller.LoginController.login()
```

Why @Controller is used is to differentiate requests to pages and rest calls. Please correct me if I am wrong. My idea is to use @RestController s for REST requests, on the other hand @Controller for pages related requests- redirecting to JSP or any logics related to views. Is it a bad practice ?

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be invoked"? As in it is ignored?

Comment: @Synch. Thanks for your attention. if localhost:8080/login is called, it returns 404

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Why does it return a 404 when I use @Controller annotation?

When using `@Controller`, Spring expects the `String` you return in `@RequestMapping` methods to correspond to the page you want to redirect the user to.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method= RequestMethod.GET )
public String login() {
    return "Login Controller";
}
```

Here, Spring will try to redirect the user to `Login Controller.jsp`, which cannot be found and thus returns a `404`.

#### Why does it not return 404 when I use @RestController

When using `@RestController`, the `String` you return is not mapped to any page. Instead, Spring just transforms it to e.g. a JSON response. This is why this doesn't give you a `404`.

#### Proposed solution

If you have a jsp page called `login.jsp`, simply return `"login"`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method= RequestMethod.GET )
public String login() {
    return "login";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. My question is, why then the log shows me that controller is pointed and its method ? (INFO 532 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/login],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sbootsecurityjsp.controller.LoginController.login()
)  Why it looks for a page instead of a controller ? - Is it because that the @Controller ?   Frankly, my attempt was to add a page as you suggested. It did not work. Then I tried to test whether this controller works simply by making the controller return a text.

Comment: It is not looking for a page INSTEAD of a controller. The log means the method is mapped to endpoint `/login`. So if you go to that `localhost:8080/login`, the corresponding method will be invoked. If you put a debug breakpoint there, you will see the breakpoint gets activated. Once you return the result (`"login"`), Spring will look for a page to display when you use `@Controller`. It doesn't do that in `@RestController`

Comment: I got my app working. Thanks for your explanation. There was a mapping issue for jsp pages. BTW, I learned the behavior between those controllers. Highly appreciated your support